# Defining a nonlinear capacitor in Ngspice

Tags: simulation, spice

I try to simulate an electronic circuit depicted in the  schematic below.

[image]

This circuit contains  two  nonlinear devices : 
These two devices are depending on the charge density  and are defined as follows:

\$V_S = K \cdot Q^2 \$

\$I_d = k_{d1} \cdot exp(\frac{-Q^2}{k_{d2}})\$

where  \$I = \frac{d_Q}{dt}\$

Is it possible to use the Behavioral Source?
According to the ngspice manual 25 , the nonlinear Source are only depending on the node voltages and branch current.
In my case the nonlinear Source or device depends on the integration of the branch current. 
Is it possible to  define a B-source which depends on the  integration of the branch current ?

\$ K ,\  K_{d1} \  \text{and}\    k_{d2}\$ are constant values!

\$ I_d\$ is the flowing current through the Diode-like device and is defined as follows:

\$ I_d = k_{d1} exp(\frac{-Q^2}{k_{d2}}) \$

\$ V_s\$ is the dropping voltage across the nonlinear condensator-like device and is described by the following term:

\$ V_s = k \cdot Q^2 \$

Comment: I get an error when I try to open that file. What do terms like "B-source" mean? What are I and Id, K, kd1, kd2 and Q?

Comment: "Is it possible to use the Behavioral Source?" => B-source. The link doesn't work for me either.

Comment: The annexed file URL cannot be accessed without login. I would suggest to post inline.

Comment: sorry that you couldn't see the picture.I 've given the url in the following answer!

Answer (score 4):

As you say, the behavioral source in ngspice can only generate a voltage or current as a function of other node voltages or branch currents in your circuit. Nonetheless, you can use this, with some extra elements, to produce a nonlinear capacitor like you seem to need:

[image]

Here I used a linear CCCS and a linear capacitor to do the integration of the incoming current and track the charge variable. Then a nonlinear VCVS provides the capacitive behavior of your nonlinear capacitor. The gigohm resistor is there because SPICE requires every node to have a dc path to ground in order to obtain a solution; it will not affect the circuit solution significantly.

There's a similar example, using ngSpice syntax on page 89 in the ngSpice manual [here](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs/ngspice-manual.pdf).

**Alternate solution**

Also, be aware, ngSpice offers a behavioral capacitor model, described on page 71 in the manual I linked. The syntax is

```
CXXXXXXX n+ n C = ’expression’ <tc1 = value > < tc2 = value >
```

Here you should understand that the capacitance defined is the differential capacitance

\$C \equiv \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}V}\$.

To put your equations in an appropriate form you need to re-work them a little bit. You have

\$V = K Q^2\$.

If you turn this around you have

\$Q = \sqrt{\frac{V}{K}}\$.

From which you can get

\$ \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}V} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{KV}}\$

Which you can easily implement in the ngSpice expression syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your detailed answer. 
According to the sketch, I have written a netlist as follows, but I'm wondering why the current as the output of a nonlinear circuit is still sinusoidal by a sinusoidal excitation voltage. I don't know, if there is any any logical or technical problem in the code. 
Thanks in advance!

My netlist:

```
V1 0 1 SIN(0 200 0.1k)
C0 2 1 1n
X1 3 2 nonlinDevice
L1 4 3 0.0125
R1 5 4 200
Vg 0 5 DC=30
************************************
.subckt nonlinDevice n1 n2
VDC n1 n0 DC=0
BVs n0 n2 V=v(ng)*v(ng)
BIs n1 n2 I=exp(-v(ng)*v(ng))
Bint 0 ng I=i(VDC)
Cint ng 0 1
Rint ng 0 100G
.ends
*************************************
.control
tran 0.01m 80m
plot i(l1)
.endc
.end
```

Comment: This isn't really the place to put new questions or additions to your question. But if I read it right, your circuit basically describes a diode with I_s of 1 A. Typical silicon diodes have I_s of 10^-15 or so. I suspect this is at least part of your problem.